# Making a short hand function for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a shorthand function for a build in JavaScript function:

```
function editById(getId) {
  document.getElementById(getId);
}
```

then I tried using it in my script.js:

```
function run() {
  document.editById("test").style.color="blue";
}
```

then my HTML:

```
<p id="test">TestTestestestse</p>
<input type="button" onclick="run()" value="Change text color">
```

This doesn't work with `editById`, but it does `getElementById`...

`ABOVE SOLVED`

---

Adding onto that:

Now this doesn't work:

shortHand.js

```
// Long term document functions
document.editById = function (find) { return document.getElementById(find); }
document.editByClass = function (find2) { return document.getElementsByClassName(find2); }
document.editByTag = function (find3) { return document.getElementsByTagName(find3); }
```

script.js

```
function run() {
  document.editById("test").style.color="blue";
}
function run2() {
  document.editByClass("test").style.color="blue";
}
function run3() {
  document.editByTag("h1").style.color="blue";
}
```

HTML

```
<p id="test">TestTestestestse</p>
<p class="test">TestTestestestse222</p>
<h1>TestTestestestse368585475</h1>
<input type="button" onclick="run()" value="Change text color">
<input type="button" onclick="run2()" value="Change text color">
<input type="button" onclick="run3()" value="Change text color">
```

Comment: Where did you define `document.editById`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify your function as

```
function editById(getId) {
  //return object
  return document.getElementById(getId);
}

function run() {
  editById("test").style.color="blue";
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fsyQ4/)

Additionally, You also use like

```
document.editById = function (getId) {
  return document.getElementById(getId);
}

function run() {
  document.editById("test").style.color = "blue";
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nMmzC/1/)

Comment: Ha, should have known.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Or if you want to be fancy, `var editById = document.getElementById.bind(document);`

Comment: @Xero, `document.getElementsByTagName` with return you a HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name. and `document.getElementsByClassName` will return a set of elements which have all the given class names. So you have to use like `document.editByClass("test")[0]`

Comment: I will, it wasn't letting me a sec ago.  Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

the function editById is registered on document Object but on window.
you can not call the function like this

you may call the function like this

```
function run() {
  editById("test").style.color="blue";
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work.  @Satpal fixed it my adding the `return`